# Replace " in string with \"

Tags: objective-c, json, string, nsstring, expression

I am trying to send a string to the server. I encode it and set it as the body of an HTTP request using

```
[request setHTTPBody:[body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Where body is the string.It has to be in json format.

For example

```
body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"emailBody\":\"%@\"}",string] ;
```

should be valid

But i accept string from user and it may contain double quotes.Therefore i have to escape double quotes(") in it.
For example if want to send just one "

```
{\"emailBody\":\"\\\"\"}
```

(harddcoded) returns positive response from server.

So i would like to create such a string from the original string.I tried the following

```
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\\\""];
```

But it did not work.I got \" in my test email.Thats as far as i have been able to get.

Am I taking the right approach ??I would appreciate it if someone would point me in the right direction.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should generate your JSON directly from a dictionary. That'll take care of all the encoding automatically for you:

```
NSDictionary *body = @{@"emailBody": string};
NSError *error; 
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:body options:0 error:&error];

if (!jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
} else {
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonString];
}
```

Comment: Thanks man ... I tweaked your idea bit and now i'm sending all kinds of special characters in my mail :D